# How to rename or choose twigs file name suggestions?

Tags: theming, blocks

When I create a custom block called `Lorem ipsum Dolor`, I have not the possibility to choose the machine name. So when I have to make a twig template, the file suggestion is :

> block—loremipsumdolor.html.twig

I mean it is without undescore. I found it hard to handle all these twig file when I work on a custom template. It is not human friendly readable.

Is there a way to choose the name of the file name or the block machine name ?

Other example :

> Block name : Custom Search form

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * block--customsearchform.html.twig
-->
```

I have not this problem with node :

> node--13--teaser.html.twig

Comment: You have to add your own template suggestions then. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_alter/8.2.x and look through https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=block+template+suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a block name of 'Custom Search form', you can add to the file name suggestions using a preprocess hook in your theme.

An example of code to add to the `.theme` file:

```
/**
 * Add an alternative to file name suggestions the Custom Search form block.
 *
 * Implements hook__suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 * @return array Suggestions.
*/
function mytheme_theme_suggestions_block_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
    if($variables['elements']['#id'] == 'customsearchform'){
        $suggestions[] = 'block__custom_search_form';
    }
}
```

This will result in an additional file name suggestion:

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * block--custom-search-form.html.twig * block--customsearchform.html.twig
-->
```

Comment: It seems the perfect solution. However, If I had this function to mytheme.theme, I can see in source code the new template file suggestion `block--custom-search-form.html.twig`. But if I use this template, I don’t see it in front end. If I use the normal file suggestion `block--customsearchform.html.twig`, I can see my template in front-end. Is there something  should do ?

Comment: Apologies - I made a slight error. Correcting the original answer. Twig file suggestions use underscores, which are then converted to dashes for the actual file names. So the suggestion should be `block__custom_search_form`.